# Ranger won't show image preview

Tags: terminal

some weeks ago i installed ranger on my new ubuntu machine and tried out the image preview. It did not work immediately but after some tweaks i could get the desired result.
What I did (at least what i remember)

1. install all dependencies (w3m, pillow)
2. change TERM (back) to "xterm-kitty" (i'm using Kitty)
3. set preview_images true
4. set preview_images_method w3m
   i know, it should be "kitty", but that did not work)

After i realized, that there was no way to get it to work with tmux, iwas disapointed and did not use ranger that much.

Now i switched to a tiled WM and use ranger a lot, but the image preview is not working anymore.

It would be nice if someone could help me out.

Here are the relevant parts of may ranger config:

```
# Use one of the supported image preview protocols
set preview_images true

# set preview_images_method w3m
set preview_images_method kitty # does not work in tmux
```

you can find the whole config at [my dotfiles](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/dotfiles/blob/master/config/ranger/rc.conf.symlink)

## Edit

Note this is not about apache-ranger